# how to use location.href from js and access values in php

Tags: javascript, php, get, window.location

I have the following:

```
var model='ABCD';
var from = '4/12/2016';
var to ='4/12/2017';
var line= 'A';

window.location = "data/export.php?model="+model+"&from="+from+"&to="+to+"&line="+line;
```

now I am trying to access these variables in export.PHP so I can use them in a query. Is that possible? I have been looking around and reading but it looks like it isn't?

I have tried doing:

```
$fromDate = $_GET['from '];
$toDate = $_GET['to'];
$line= $_GET['line']; 
...
```

I think this doesn't work because it is not sending them in GET but is there a way to access those in PHP?

I understand I could use ajax but there is a limitation because of a library that I am using that won't work with ajax calls so there was the suggestion to use window. location=URL is there something similar to this method that would allow me to access the variables from JS to PHP and then work with a spout download xlsx file?

I am really new to programming so I apologize if this is obvious.

Comment: Have you tried using `window.location.href`?

`window.location.href = "data/export.php?model="+model+"&from="+from+"&to="+to+"&line="+line`

Comment: I have and same behavior @lixus

Comment: from's $_GET has a space, it should be $_GET['from']

Comment: @cocopan How about `window.location.replace(url)`?

Comment: Yes, window.location or window.location.href are both acceptable and they each produce a GET request.  What directory are you running the javascript in?  In "data" or another directory?  Also in your PHP script do you have error_reporting on.  If so what error message(s) do you see.  I ran your javascript on my own box and created a PHP file in the same directory and the two worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, you are all correct. I had read other posts that confused me a lot (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php). I tried it and it looks like I have a join that is making the values not get to the query. I am using a download method so there is no error reporting it either triggers the download or not but I think I found a way to bedbug it now. I appreciate all of your help!! sorry I took your time with something so simple!